# How to make a VBox Scrollabe

Tags: java, javafx, scrollbar, vbox

I've been trying to make a VBox scrollable but nothing seems to work. Could anyone please help and advise me on what I might be doing wrong? Thank you all in advance.

This is what I have, but I just can't seem to make it work:

```
@Component
@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS, value = "prototype")
public class Scroller {

    final ScrollBar sc = new ScrollBar();
    DropShadow shadow = new DropShadow();

    public Group scrollableGroup(VBox Container) {
        Group root = new Group();
        root.getChildren().addAll(Container, sc);

        shadow.setColor(Color.GREY);
        shadow.setOffsetX(2);
        shadow.setOffsetY(2);

        sc.setLayoutX(500 + sc.getWidth() + 10);
        sc.setMin(0);
        sc.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        sc.setPrefHeight(500);
        sc.setMax(500 * 2);

        sc.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov,
                    Number old_val, Number new_val) {
                Container.setLayoutY(-new_val.doubleValue());
            }
        });

        return root;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's ScrollPane class that works as a wrapper around nodes / containers. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html You should create a ScrollPane instance and call setContent() on it with your VBox object as the parameter

Comment: I know about ScrollPane @AlmasB. I'm just resaerching on how to go about it using a VBox

Comment: The way you "go about it using a `VBox`" is exactly as @AlmasB described: put the `VBox` inside the `ScrollPane`.

Answer (score 0):

AlmasB and James_D are right—the easiest way is just to put the VBox in a ScrollPane. If you're doing this for the fun of it, Oracle's ScrollBar tutorial walks you through exactly how to make a VBox scrollable.

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/scrollbar.htm